# Program is reading the largest number from a file, but not the smallest

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I am writing a program that reads integers from an input file, and finds the smallest and largest number and outputs it, using a while loop. My output file is successfully showing that it found the largest number, but it says that the smallest number is 0, even though in my input file the smallest number is 11. Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
fstream instream;
instream.open("lab7_input.txt");
ofstream outstream;
outstream.open("lab7_output.txt");

int next, largest, smallest;
largest = 0;
smallest = 0;

while (instream >> next)
{
    if (largest < next)
    {
        largest = next;
    }
    if (smallest > next)
    {
        smallest = next;
    }
}

outstream << "The largest number is: " << largest << endl;
outstream << "The smallest number is: " << smallest << endl;
instream.close();
outstream.close();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialize smallest to a larger value, perhaps, or else enter values < 0, as you initialized it to zero.

Comment: You initialize `smallest` to 0, so unless you have negative numbers in your file, 0 will always be smaller.  You can instead initialize it to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()` to avoid this.

Comment: How about initializing smallest to the biggest value it can hold ?

Comment: I'm quite sure this is identical to a question I saw yesterday.

Comment: Setting the line `smallest = 0` to a number that was larger than every other number in the file I was reading from worked. Thank you everyone! I did `smallest 999;`

Answer (score 2):

This is your issue: `smallest = 0;`

When testing for minimums/maximums, try initializing your `min` or `max` variables to their opposite end of the spectrum. Use `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` to do this. Try this:

```
#include <climits>

...

int next, largest, smallest;
largest = INT_MIN;
smallest = INT_MAX;
```

Now your program is ensured to have the largest/smallest values, no matter what's in your number set.

Comment: No problem! If you feel that your question was answered, make sure to accept one of the responses.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend setting largest and smallest to the first value read:

```
instream >> largest;
smallest = largest;
while (instream >> next)
//...
```

This allows your answers to specify the largest and smallest in the given set of numbers.  Setting to numerical limits, doesn't specify a number within the set.

Answer (score 1):

if(smallest > next) but if smallest is 0 it would never be greater than next
so it always stuck to zero ,
to make the program run set smallest = 99999999 // high number at the beggining

Comment: @AndriNic "_set smallest = 99999999_" What if the smallest number would be `999999999`? Better set it to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Comment: I would advise against using `numeric_limits<T>::max()`  and instead ensuring that the container is not empty and simply setting `T min = elements[0]`.

Comment: @Habitate "_I would advise against using `numeric_limits<T>::max()`_" Any reason why? "_instead ensuring that the container is not empty and simply setting `T min = elements[0]`._" What container? OP is reading these elements from stream. Wouldn't `if` statement checking if it was the first element read, more cumbersome, than just initializing the value correctly?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, I was talking about the general way of finding min values inside a container (this can be achieved by using stream iterators as well). However, I don't see any problem simply doing `stream >> smallest` before the loop.

Comment: @Habitate 1) "_I don't see any problem simply doing stream >> smallest before the loop._" What if `stream` is empty? 2) You, still, didn't answer the question of why would you advise against `numeric_limits<T>::max()`? Any advice, without reasoning is worthless.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius, because either way you have to check for container size since the max/min values would be invalid otherwise.